# RelativeLayout Params addRule without ID

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I want to add the following rule to a TextView within my RelativeLayout

```
TextView anyView = new TextView(anyContext);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout;
..
layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, anyView.getID());
```

This only works if I add the ID of the element. The problem is that I do not have and do not want to have any IDs specified, because my view can be used multiple times within the same ViewGroup later.

So either I have to assign that rule by reference or I need to create new IDs dynamically so that I don't create multiple Views with the same ID.

Any suggestions what to do in this situation?

I tried to copy from this xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A lot of text for some width"/>
        </GridLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: how you want the items to be aligned ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pAC = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            your width,
                            your height);

                    pAC.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                    anyView .setLayoutParams(pAC);
```

Comment: Thats not enough to center my TextView. I have edited my post so you might get an idea of what I want.

Comment: If you want the the textview then set the textview's to match_parent and then set the gravity to center.Is that what you want?

Comment: With match_parent my TextView overlaps my GridLayout

Comment: Then set  your textview as : pAC.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is not working as well. The only working setup I found is ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT with LEFT_OF

Comment: if u think the above answer helped you then accept the answer.Thank You!

Comment: Like I said it`s not working the way you said. Currently I got only my idea to work but then I need to specify the ID and I don`t want that